# pgfplots: locally activating linear scale in a log scale plot

Tags: pgfplots, scaling

I have the following short example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=2.4,xmax=2.6,ymode=log,ymin=0.1,ymax=10]
\fill[red] (axis cs:2.5,1) circle (1);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to *inactivate* the log scale on the red circle *only* to essentially see it as a circle. Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A circle will appear a circle independent of the axis used since it is't entered as data or a table of values. The problem with your code is merely of specifying the unit of length of the radius. Is it 1pt, 1in, 1cm? you should specify.

Here is what I get if I specify 1cm, for example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=2.4,xmax=2.6,ymode=log,ymin=0.1,ymax=10]
\fill[red] (axis cs:2.5,1) circle (1cm);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting. I would not have thought about this!